# Extract value from Option of List

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have option of list of string and i know in that list there would be only one value.

```
val a = Option[List["value"]]
```

How do i obtain the value of a in scala in the most decent way possible?

Comment: This code will not compile. If this is just a value and you are certain it will never be empty, just use `a.get.head`. Otherwise, you should provide more context (and correct code) for others to be able to give useful help.

Answer (score 7):

Since, `List` also can be empty, by it's type definition, I'd recommend next way:

```
val value: Option[String] = a.flatMap(_.headOption)
```

so, `headOption` - returns `Option` of list first element, so `value` will be `Some` if both outer `Option` and internal `List` are non empty.

There is also `List.head` operation, which returns `T` value or throw exception in case if list absent - but because of possible exception, I'd recommend to try to avoid it usage, and handle empty list case explicitly.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Direct answer to your question, checking if the list in the `Option` contains only one value will be

```
 a.exists(_.length == 1)
```